# What movie are the following gifs of angels from?

Tags: story-identification, movie

Maybe someone can help me out, I can't figure out what the name is of the movie seen in these gifs:

[image]
[image]

These are two short segments from live action scenes.  The first one shows a woman with long black hair dressed as an angel with large wings and a halo, walking towards the camera. The second shows the same angel from the side, turning her head towards another angel.

Comment: See [meta](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7343/19561) for further discussion regarding the topicality of this question.

Comment: See also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/103224/4918 "What sci-fi show is this gif from?" for an earlier question where the answer is a shampoo ad.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This isn't a movie. It's a commercial for the *Axe* brand (also known as *Lynx* in some countries) of body spray / deodorant / antiperspirant.

The music is a cover version of Air's "Sexy Boy".

Comment: I've found versions of the commercial that label it as being for Axe. Not sure if it goes by Lynx Excite in other countries, though. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqieLZ3UKP0

Comment: Axe is known as Lynx in the UK, Republic of Ireland, Australia, New Zealand and China according to Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axe_(brand)

Comment: Axe/Lynx is also known by some as an *antiperspirant* or *deoderent*.