# What sci-fi show is this gif from?

Tags: story-identification

I found this GIF in a [random image gallery](http://www.ebaumsworld.com/pictures/view/84730141/).  It is a live action scene with multiple cuts.  It shows Star Wars style humanoid aliens with various distinctive looks, including one with two heads and one with an elephant trunk, together with humans in a crowded indoor scene.  Doing a Google image search came up with no matches. It looks like something I'd enjoy, so I'd really like to find out what show or movie it is:

[image]

**Does anyone recognize where this scene is from?**

Comment: @Richard The question from that link should also be closed as off-topic...

Comment: Questions don't *become* off-topic because we don't like the answer.

Comment: Nor do questions become off-topic because we do not like the medium through which science fiction or fantasy are expressed.

Comment: Please don't use the comments box for prolonged discussion. If you have an issue, press the close button or take it to meta

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's from a [TV advert](http://www.bohemianpictures.cz/) for Herbal Essences hair products and shampoos.

You can view the full ad on Vimeo [here](https://vimeo.com/105951887)

[image]

Comment: “It looks like something I'd enjoy” — and *did* you?

Comment: I enjoyed it greatly. Especially the part where they tried to sell me shampoo.

Comment: ROFL!! Does that mean the question is off-topic?

Comment: @randal'thor - Technically yes. The story-ident ultimately leads to an advert but I'm minded to leave it open. The clip is clearly intended to fit into a "scifi genre"

Comment: Well, DANG. I was hoping this would lead to some Farscapesque sci-fi show I hadn't seen yet.

Comment: @Omegacron - Nope. On the plus side, your hair will have a wonderful lustrous shine.

Comment: “I was hoping this would lead to some Farscapesque sci-fi show” — if we can muster the will to post enough bottles of Tabasco sauce somewhere, *it might still*.

Comment: @Richard How did you find this answer though?

Comment: @MarchHo - I used a combination of amazingness and awesomeosity. I like to call it awzingmazinessomity.

Comment: @MarchHo - Google images is your friend, just be aware that when you google a gif, it only searches the first frame.

Comment: Looks like the video was taken down on YouTube :( You might want to update the answer with a brief summary and the brand of shampoo