# Beer Commercial - Men Devolve into Salamanders - "Worth the wait"

Tags: story-identification, advertisements

I saw this commercial years ago. It starts out in a bar, with three guys having a beer, and suddenly this (kinda catchy) music starts playing and time seems to reverse, and everything around them starts to devolve, including the guys.

As the Earth devolves thru the eons, our thirsty men devolve into primates, maybe other more primitive animals, then finally into salamanders at the edge of a muddy watering hole. The salamanders then go "bleh!".  And then, I think, a narrator says something like "Worth the wait", referring to some beer.

Also, I don't know if it has anything to do with it, but I think "Una Brita" was in the name of the video of it I saw, but I'm not sure.

So, does anyone know or remember this commercial, and it's subject?  And, is it available to view online (link or other reference)?

Comment: Before anyone votes to close this see [this relevant id question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/81579/58193) about an advert (admittedly they didn't know it was one) and the [ensuing meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7343/58193) about it which deemed it on topic.

Comment: I think I saw this in a *Star Trek:  Voyager* episode.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the [*noitulovE*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoitulovE) Guinness advert that first ran in 2005 and was the fifth in the "Good things come to those who wait" campaign.

The men actually finally de-evolve into mudskippers not salamanders.

You can view it online here:

---

<sub><sup>*For those wondering I actually remembered this advert from when it ran on TV. However, I thought it was for Budweiser (don't know why!) and so Googled `budweiser ad evolution` to find a video of it. The ad still came up and showed it was for Guinness.*</sup></sub>

Comment: As an added bonus [here is the ad but in reverse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zDVh95sQ11g).

Comment: Thanks! My google-fu was short circuited as I tried searching for "beer commercial men devolve", instead of "evolution".  The same search now turns up this question as it's top TWO hits, after only a day! :)  And, actual video is now listed a little further down the search resultes - but I swear it didn't find it all before!

Comment: @SelfEvident Google results are tailored so as you’ve visited the links would be more likely to show up.